# ¿Con qué tecnología se puede exponer consola y editor de texto en la web como hackerrank o similares? Ojala con python, sino aprender otro skill

Tags: web, stack

tengo un proyecto en mente, algo similar a hackerrank, pero no se con qué tecnología podría hacer algo así.

Particularmente, tener un editor de texto online, una consola que muestre el resultado de ese texto ejecutado, y si es posible mostrar test unitarios de ese mismo codigo.

Me manejo un poco con python, si hay algo por ahí sería genial, sino solo queda aprender :)

Muchas gracias a quien pueda orientarme un poco

Comment: Con python tiene librerias web para hacer eso.

Comment: Y tienen alguna recomendación particular?